# C++ char* and C# bytes

Tags: c#, c++, winsock

I'm coding a C++ app that communicates with a C# app over TCP, and I'm stuck on this problem:

- In C# I call `send` and `receive` for the sockets and that returns a `byte[]`. I also send and receive `int`s using `BitConverter.GetBytes()`/`BitConverter.ToInt32()`.
- In C++ I use `send` and `recv` for the sockets. That uses `char*`, and for the `int`s I use `atoi()`/`itoa()`.

How do i make these two things communicate?
Is `char*` a series of `Int16` in some encoding?
What do `BitConverter` and `atoi`/`itoa` really do?

Comment: If you are sending strings to/from the C++ side (indicated by `atoi` and `itoa`), then you could do the same on the C# side (where you currently seem to be sending in a binary format).

Comment: A `char` is *always* a byte (whatever that may be considered on that system). Therefore, `byte[]` in C# and `char[]` (`char *`) in C++ are the same type.

Comment: From the socket you receive a stream of bytes. You can than convert that stream of bytes into whatever entities you expect this stream to represent. When sending ints, watch out for endianness.

Comment: Keep in mind that you generally don't control the chunkiness of the byte stream. Packets can be split or coalesced. You can only depend on bytes arriving in order, not on receiving N bytes at once because you just sent N bytes at once.

Answer (score 1):

In C/C++, char* can hold characters encoded as ASCII or UTF-8, so that is fairly easy, just use them as-is.

In C#, you will probably need to specify a conversion since C# uses 2-byte wide characters, such as

```
String s = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(my_byte_array, 0, count);
```

where my_byte_array is whatever holds the bytes you receive, and count is the number of bytes that were actually loaded from the TCP connection (should be reported by the code that reads it).

You should also be encoding, with something like

```
byte[] b = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(my_string_to_send);
```

There are many Encoding types, in case you need to support an alternate format - for example, in C# you could use Encoding.Unicode to send 16-bit wide characters, and in C++ use wchar_t* to capture them.  Check Microsoft's documentation on the C# Encoding class here:

```
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding(v=vs.110).aspx
```

I don't know how you intend to tell the difference between an Int32 and a string, but as long as you have a way, char* and Encoding.ASCII should work just fine for you.

Edited to answer final question: atoi/itoa just take a string and convert it into an binary integer or the other way around (e.g. "1234" is four bytes in memory, containing the values 49, 50, 51, 52.  atoi("1234") returns an int that contains 1234; itoa reverses that, taking 1234 and writing the four bytes).   BitConverter does not do the same thing; instead, it takes 4 bytes in memory containing e.g. 0, 0, 4, 210 and allows C#.NET to treat it as an integer (or any other type) even though it is encoded exactly as an integer would be.  BitConverter is the equivalent of a typecast in C++, like

```
*((int*)byte_array)
```

and may not be what you want, depending on how you signal whether you are sending text or numeric data.

Answer (score 1):

`BitConverter` appears to deal with the pure binary values of the integers that you pass. You can create equivalents to `BitConverter.GetBytes()` and `BitConverter.ToInt32` in C++ with the following (assuming the same endianness on both computers):

```
void GetBytes(int32_t value, char *dest)
{
    if (!dest) return;
    memcpy(dest, &value, sizeof(value));
}

int32_t ToInt32(char *buf, size_t pos)
{
    if (!buf) return 0;
    return *(reinterpret_cast<int32_t *>(buf + pos));
}
```

`BitConverter.GetBytes(23)` would return `{0x17, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00}` as a `byte[]`, while `BitConverter.ToInt32` would reverse the operation.

`atoi` and `itoa` are C functions that convert a sequence of characters to what they appear to be. They are short for "ASCII to int" and "int to ASCII". For example, `atoi("34")` would return `34` as an `int`.

Comment: This Works perfectly! Is it worth using BitConverter and this functions or is there a better approach on the c# side?

Comment: If you're sending over TCP, `BitConverter` is a perfectly logical choice. However, if you wish to avoid confusion such as endianness with different platforms, as well as a multitude of other issues involving creating your own binary format, I'd recommend abstracting using XML, JSON or even [BSON](http://bsonspec.org/).

Comment: ASN.1 works also. For compactness, use a binary form of ASN.1 or gzip the stream if using XML, JSON, …,